# <table> attributes not working

Tags: html, css

I tried adding border and aligning my table center but its not working.
What is the reason? What causes my code to ignore the attributes of the table?
So far I also tried adding `style='border:1;'` to it but it still doesn't work.

```
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='../CSS/style.css' media="all"/>
    </head>
<body>  
            <!--Main Wrapper starts here!-->
    <div class="main_wrapper"> 

            <!--Header Wrapper starts here!-->
        <div class="header_wrapper" >

        <a href='index.php'><img id="logo" src="../Pictures/logo.png"/></a>
        </div>
            <!--Header ends here!-->

            <!--Menu Bar starts here!-->
        <div class="menubar">

        <div id="form">
            <form method="get" action="results.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <!--<input type="text" name="user_query"  placeholder="Search Product"/>
                <input type="submit" name="search" value="search" style='background-color:#80dfff; border:none;'/>-->
            </form> 
        </div>
        </div><!--Menubar ends here!-->

            <!--Content Wrapper here!-->
        <div class="content_wrapper">

            <!--CONTENT AREA starts here-->
            <div id="content_area">
            <a href='admin_login.php' style='color:white; font-size:20px; position:absolute;top:275px; right:210px;'>
            Logout</a>

            <table align ='center' border = '1'>
            <tr>
                <td>CustomerID</td>
                <td>ItemID</td>
                <td>Price</td>
                <td>Quantity</td>
                <td>Total</td>
                <td>Date</td>
            </tr>

            </table>
            </div><!--END OF CONTENT AREA-->
        </div><!--Content Wrapper ends here!-->
        <div id="footer"><h2 style='text-align:center; padding-top:25px;'>&copy; Jerlon Buenconsejo 2015</h2> </div>
    </div><!--Wrapper-->
</body>
</html>
```

**STYLESHEET**

```
body{

    background:url('../Pictures/background_login.jpg');
}

input[type='text']{

    height:50px;
    width: 250px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    opacity: .5;
    border: none;
}
input[type='password']{

    height:50px;
    width: 250px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    opacity: .5;
    border: none;
}

input[type='submit']{
    position:relative;
    top:-330px;
    left:50px;
    height:50px;
    width: 250px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 11px;
    background-color:#27b061 ;
}

label{

    font-family:courier;
    font-size: 18;
    display:inline;
    color:white;


}

#emailtext{
    margin-left: 52px;
}
#login_wrapper{
margin-top:150px;

}

.formdata{
position:relative;
top:-350px;
padding:10px;
padding-left:10px;
text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: I tried that code in my browser and it does center the table and add the border. My guess is that you have some styles in your css that are overriding your table inline style. Comment out your stylesheet link to see the result, and if so, look the through the css file to find it.

Comment: @amespower I've edited it and added the stylesheet.

Comment: yep, it works with the styles added according to your expectations set in your question, bordered and centered. Check out the fiddle:  https://jsfiddle.net/v3e3y93y/  What is not working?

Comment: If your stylesheet is overriding your inline styles, you can try adding `!important` to give the priority to the inline styles. E.g. `table align="center !important;"`. Use the browser "inspect element" tool to see what's going on.